# Integration BannerviewController In project

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, iad

I created a project without storyboard and xib. I have multiple views and wanted a shared banner to be displayed on all views. I went through the sample code given by apple and tried to use the BannerViewController.h and .m files but I am not getting any proper output. Can u please tell me how to properly make the iAd work in my project.

From Below Link i downloaded the IAd sample code 
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/iAdSuite/Introduction/Intro.html

I added the bannerviewcontroller.h and m files with in my project.
In my application MainViewcontroller, the NSNotificationCenter is not getting called and no banner is display.

```
#import "BannerViewController.h"

 - (void)viewDidLoad {
            [super viewDidLoad];
            [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(willBeginBannerViewActionNotification:) name:BannerViewActionWillBegin object:nil];
            [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(didFinishBannerViewActionNotification:) name:BannerViewActionDidFinish object:nil];
        }

- (void)willBeginBannerViewActionNotification:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    NSLog(@"Will begin banner view action notification");
}

- (void)didFinishBannerViewActionNotification:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    NSLog(@"Did finish banner view action notification");
}
```

Please let me know what i missed.

Thanking you in advance!

Comment: If you don't use a storyboard or a .xib you need to set your rootviewcontroller in your app delegate... have you done that?

Comment: And are you actually loading the banner? Can we see your appdelegate and your mainviewcontroller code?

Comment: AppDel- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {
self.viewController = [[MainViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MainViewController_iPhone" bundle:nil];
} else {
self.viewController = [[MainViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MainViewController_iPad" bundle:nil];}
self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
return YES;}

Comment: - (void)willBeginBannerViewActionNotification:(NSNotification *)notification{} - (void)didFinishBannerViewActionNotification:(NSNotification *)notification{}                                    - (void)viewDidLoad{ [super viewDidLoad];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(willBeginBannerViewActionNotification:) name:BannerViewActionWillBegin object:nil]; [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(didFinishBannerViewActionNotification:) name:BannerViewActionDidFinish object:nil];}

Comment: I imported BannerViewController.h to my MainviewController and calling a notification in ViewDidLoad . I thought this will call the BannerViewController and load the banner. please help. little confused.